# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am using Jboss EAP 7.2.6 and trying to deploy and EJB3 application. I am getting below error during the application deployment.

````
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.6.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.SerializationHackProxy.proxy(SerializationHackProxy.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.6.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.iiop.handle.HandleDelegateImpl.<init>(HandleDelegateImpl.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.6.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.bindService(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.2.6.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(IIOPJndiBindingProcessor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.server@6.0.21.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144) ```
````

Comment: What does the rest of the stack trace look like?

Comment: I have the same issue when using Java 17,